# IOS 7 sending link in email, &section getting replaced with section symbol

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm trying to send a link in an email. The link has a query string parameter called section so it's like:

```
mysite.com/?story=12345&section=news
```

I'm using the MFMailComposeViewController and setting the message body to the string that contains my URL. It is replacing the `&sect` portion of my string with the section symbol (looks like a double s or a snake). It should not be doing this! There is not a semicolon `;` after `&sect` in my string, which would be the html entity for the section symbol. It looks like this:

```
mysite.com/?story=12345§ion=news
```

Anybody run into this problem or have a solution?

Comment: Well, as a workaround you could swap the order, `?section=news&story=12345`

Comment: When you call `setMessageBody:isHTML:` are you passing `YES` or `NO`?

Comment: Passing NO, but also tried YES - same result either way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mysite.com/?story=12345&amp;section=news
```

Let see is set if escaping the ampersand works

Comment: I think you need a semi-colon after the `amp`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to tell the MFMailComposeViewController that your body text is *not* HTML. Try this:

```
[mailView setMessageBody:urltext isHTML:NO];
```